# Minecraft and graphics card

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got the open-GL thing because my graphics card is up to date. There is no new update out for it. I have a Nevada card, windows 10 system. I did try to reinstall minecraft but it made no difference. Is there like a version that is the same but does not use this open-GL thing?

Comment: What is your graphics card? Have you been able to play Minecraft in the past? If so, have you recently changed anything?

Comment: I have played minecraft in the past. This just started happening a good 2 days ago. it seems to be a "GEFORCE GTX 765m" hope that is it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Minecraft is based on OpenGL-rendering, that's why it runs on all OSes supporting Java. Windows 10 has problems with OpenGL-rendering for what reason when the latest Java version is used. This happened to me too after upgrading to Windows 10.

I can play Minecraft without any problems with Java 8 Update 45. Uninstall Java and install [this (32-bit)](http://www.filehorse.com/download-java-runtime-64/20376/) version, but using outdated Java versions comes with lacks of security.

It seems like newer Java versions cause these problems.